# Can I vectorize this matrix task in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a square matrix `A` which I would like to manipulate using a matrix `D`. The result will be the matrix `B`. The entry `B(i, j)` will be a sum of a number of elements from `A(:, j)`, as determined by `D`.

Let me show what I have in codes -

```
A = magic(3); % initial matrix
D = [1, 2, 3; 2, 2, 3; 1, 3, 1]; % map matrix
B = zeros(3); % resultant matrix
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:3
        B(D(i, j), j) = B(D(i, j), j) + A(i, j);
    end
end
```

Now, to explain we have `D` as :

```
D = [1, 2, 3; 
     2, 2, 3; 
     1, 3, 1];
```

These `D` values basically act as the row indices to accumulate into output array `B`, while column indices would be iterating numbers themselves -

```
col = [1 2 3;
       1 2 3;
       1 2 3];
```

Thus, the summations are :

```
B(1,1) += A(1,1)  % Indices from first row from D to select B
B(2,2) += A(1,2)
B(3,3) += A(1,3)

B(2,1) += A(2,1)  % Indices from second row from D to select B
B(2,2) += A(2,2)
B(3,3) += A(2,3)

B(1,1) += A(3,1)  % Indices from third row from D to select B
B(3,2) += A(3,2)
B(1,3) += A(3,3)
```

Thus, at `B(1,1)` we would accumulate two values from `A` : `A(1,1)` and `A(3,1)` and so on.

When the matrices are large, this process takes a long time. Is there a way to vectorize this computation?

Comment: I don't understand your example. Your code seems to be adding `B(1,1) + A(1,1)` to get `B(1,1)`.

Comment: @beaker Note that `B(1, 1)` starts at zero.

Comment: How does matrix `D` tell you that `A(1,1)` will be added to `A(3,1)`?

Comment: @LuisMendo The entry `D(3, 1)` is also one.

Comment: @OpenSeason Got it. But the question could use some more explaining

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[m,n] = size(A);

% Generate all linear indices corresponding to D
idx = bsxfun(@plus,D,m*(0:n-1))

% Use accumarray to accumulate values for each of those indices.
% We need some reshaping to get a final 2D output after feeding in column
% vectors for using accumarray
Bout = reshape(accumarray(idx(:),A(:),[m*n,1]),[m,n])
```

Sample run -

```
>> % Setup inputs and run loopy version
A = randi(9,4,6);
D = randi(size(A,1),4,6);
B = zeros(size(A));
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    for j = 1:size(A,2)
        B(D(i, j), j) = B(D(i, j), j) + A(i, j);
    end
end

% Proposed vectorized method
>> [m,n] = size(A);
>> idx = bsxfun(@plus,D,m*(0:n-1));
>> Bout = reshape(accumarray(idx(:),A(:),[m*n,1]),[m,n]);

% Verify results
>> max(abs(Bout(:)-B(:)))
ans =
     0
```

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you!  It just took me a while to test out.